# Defining piecewise function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to use a soliton plus a step for my initial condition for KdV equation, however when I try running the code, it is unable to execute my first order difference scheme. I believe the issue is with how I defined my step function H(x)-which is a piecewise function, using 'syms'. I include a sample of my code below for reference.

```
close all
clear
clc
% Generating grid with n points, with the space between two points being
%(x2-x1)/(n-1)
x = linspace(-5,5,1001); 
N=1001;
h=x(2)-x(1); % grid size
dt=0.05;
%Soliton initial condition
Am=8; %Amplitude
mu=sqrt(Am/2);
x0=-15;
c=1;
syms H(x)
H(x)=piecewise(x < 0,0,x > 0,1);
u= Am*(sech(mu*(x'))).^2+c^2*H(x);

% Creating a matrix A - First order
A = diag(ones(N-1,1),1)-diag(ones(N-1,1),-1);
Cvector = zeros(N, 1);
Cvector(end) = 1;
u_ic = Cvector;

% First order finite difference scheme
diff_first=A*u/(2*h)+1/(2*h)*u_ic;
```

I am new to Matlab so I am not sure if my use of syms is correct in this context.

Comment: Could you copy and paste the error that you got into your question?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to define H from scratch, you can simply replace `H(x)` with `heaviside(x)`; see [heaviside](https://mathworks.com/help/symbolic/heaviside.html).

---

I can't know this without more information, but I suspect that the issue is that you're trying to use `x` in a symbolic expression when you've already defined `x` as a variable. Instead, replace

```
syms H(x)
H(x)=piecewise(x < 0,0,x > 0,1);
```

with

```
syms y
H(y) = piecewise(y<0,0,y>=0,1);
```

Comment: There is actually no error, instead the code just runs indefinitely until I stop it! I tried changing the variable, as suggested, with no luck unfortunately.

Comment: @dannyt When you stop the code (using ctl+C I assume), does it tell you what line of the program you stopped on?

Comment: yes it does, it stops on the line 'diff_first=A*u/(2*h)+1/(2*h)*u_ic;'.
When I remove the step H(x), the code runs fine...

Comment: When you remove the step `H(x)`, then what happens to `u`?

Comment: @dannyt Perhaps matlab is running into an issue with an NaN when you plug 0 into H...

Comment: Perhaps I need to apply 'subs' function first to substitute values for variables for H(x), although I am not sure how to go about that.

Comment: @dannyt Did you try using `heaviside` as I suggested in my edit?

Comment: yes that seemed to work - thank you!